# EDK2 failed to build in Win11

Tags: windows-11, edk2

I started with Visual Studio 2019 Professional, but there were some errors. I thought it was a compiler error at first, so I changed to Visual Studio 2019 Community. Error 7000 (edk2) : Microsoft Visual Studio \2019\ Professional \VC nmake.exe failed to execute command Then I changed back to VS2019 Professional, but now it is error 7000: Failed to execute Command
D: Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133bin\Hostx86\x86\nmake.exe /nologo tbuild [c:\edk2\Build\EmulatorIA32\DEBUG_VS2019\IA32\MdeModulePkg\Library\UefiHiiLib\UefiHiiLib]

Answer (score 0):

try to switch to an older stable release of edk2, like `edk2-202105`.

and also try to execute the compilation command from visual studio developer prompt or powershell.